# Ensure Singleton call db query only once

Tags: c#, singleton

I'm trying to create one object that will be responsible for reading all users access settings.

I've created class as so:

```
public class SettingsManager
{
    private static string _connString =
        @"Data Source=MyDB;Initial Catalog=IT;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing=true;";
    private const string _spName = "SettingTest";
    private IEnumerable<string> _mySettings;
    private static readonly Lazy<SettingsManager> _instance = new Lazy<SettingsManager>(() => new SettingsManager());

    private SettingsManager()
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Hello from constructor");
        if (_mySettings == null)
            _mySettings = ReadSettings();
    }

    public static SettingsManager Instance
    {
        get { return _instance.Value; }
    }

    public bool CanDo(string setting)
    {
        return _mySettings.Contains(setting);
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> ReadSettings()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = _spName;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    conn.Open();
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        return reader.Select(SettingParser).ToList();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return null;
    }

    private string SettingParser(SqlDataReader r)
    {
        try
        {
            return r[0] is DBNull ? null : r[0].ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And SqlDataReader Extension

```
public static class DBExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(
        this SqlDataReader reader, Func<SqlDataReader, T> projection)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            yield return projection(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Then inside my application I'm able to call it as so:

```
SettingsManager.Instance.CanDo("canWrite")
```

this returns true/false value depends on user access level.

My questions are:

1. Is this thread safe? Are there any chances DB will be query multiple times? How to prevent this?
2. Should I use await and async? I query db just once. How can I improve this? (await and async are really new to me because I just moved from .NET3.5 to 4.5)

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: @Ravi - I'm using one of that pattern - Lazy<>

Comment: @Ravi - http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/19/c-system.lazylttgt-and-the-singleton-design-pattern.aspx LazySingleton3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Is this thread safe?

Yes.

> Are there any chances DB will be query multiple times?

No.

> 2) Should I use await and async?

That will depend on whether you need asynchronous access to your database. If you need that you could use the async ADO.NET API.

Comment: simple, fast and nice answer :) Just wanted to ensure that my code is ok :)

Comment: Yes, your code is safe. `Lazy<T>` is a thread-safe class, so your singleton pattern is properly implemented. Also you are correctly disposing all IDisposable resources by wrapping them in using statements which is great.

Answer (score 1):

**1)yes this is, thread  safe**

Thread-safe Singleton:
This implementation uses an inner class to make the .NET instantiation fully lazy. Only GetInstance() will trigger the type initializer; so, this version is just as lazy as the classic version. And, it will perform as quckly as any other version.

```
public sealed class Singleton
{

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton GetInstance()
   {
      return NestedSingleton.singleton;
   }

   class NestedSingleton
   {
      internal static readonly Singleton singleton = new Singleton();

      static NestedSingleton() {}
   }
}
```

**2)It's depend if you want asynchronous access to your DB.**

Comment: You cannot use the `this` keyword inside a static member.

Comment: 1. Anti-pattern using this for locking, 2. Lazy<> actually is thread-safe

Comment: @CuongLe - yes, Lazy<> is thread-safe-I just need to ensure I will call my query just once. My code should be fine, but maybe there are ways to improve it :)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is this thread safe?

Yes. You are using the `Lazy<T>` type correctly to ensure thread-safety.

> 1. Should I use await and async?

I would recommend it. Right now, the first time your application code calls `SettingsManager.Instance.CanDo("canWrite")`, it will block until the DB responds. It's also possible to have an `async` implementation where your consumers could do `(await SettingsManager.Instance).CanDo("canWrite")` (or `await SettingsManager.CanDoAsync("canWrite")`). This means your consumers do not block while waiting for the DB.

You can use an `async`-ready version of `Lazy<T>` called `AsyncLazy<T>`, [originally developed by Stephen Toub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/15/10116210.aspx) and [included in my AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncLazy).

Comment: thanks for this answer, I think I try to do second version of CanDo with async :)